# Auto text to link in php

Tags: php

I have a code to convert all links in text into real html links

```
//add auto link
$oldMessage =  $discussion->message;
$newMessage = preg_replace('!((http\:\/\/|ftp\:\/\/|https\:\/\/)|www\.)([-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?!ism', '<a  href="//$3" target="_blank" ">$1$3</a>',$oldMessage);
$discussion->message = $newMessage;
```

to understand this better this is $oldMessage example text

```
<div>Hier eine Liste der Protokolle von Medi-Learn:</div>
<br><br>
<div>http://www.medi-learn.de/pruefungsprotokolle/facharztpruefung/detailed.php?ID=1266</div>

<a href="google.de">test</a>

<br><div>http://www.medi-learn.de/pruefungsprotokolle/facharztpruefung/detailed.php?ID=1231</div>
<br><div>http://www.medi-learn.de/pruefungsprotokolle/facharztpruefung/detailed.php?ID=1221</div>
<br><div>http://www.medi-learn.de/pruefungsprotokolle/facharztpruefung/detailed.php?ID=1188</div>
<br><div>http://www.medi-learn.de/pruefungsprotokolle/facharztpruefung/detailed.php?ID=1187</div>
<br><div>http://www.medi-learn.de/pruefungsprotokolle/facharztpruefung/detailed.php?ID=1178</div></div>
```

The problem is that is does not work if the orginal $oldMessage already contains links (see test) !?!?

Any solution for this ?

Comment: By `doesn't work` you mean it links the link, or fails? You are over escaping, since `/` isn't a delimiter it doesn't need to be escaped. Also,  `the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-).`- http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: I added more info to question - please check

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for me

```
preg_match_all('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', $content, $matches);

            foreach ($matches[0] as $key=>$link) {
                if (!preg_match('!<a(.*)'.$link.'(.*)/a>!i', $content))
                {
                    $content = str_replace($link, '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>', $content);
                }
            }
```